# How to insert NULL in to date field Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE pledge
(
    pledge_ID            NUMBER NOT NULL ,
    pledge_endDate       DATE NULL ,
    pledge_startDate     DATE NULL  ,
    pledge_amount        DECIMAL(9,2) NULL  CONSTRAINT  Currency_1322638346 CHECK (pledge_amount >= 0),
    artist_userID        NUMBER NOT NULL,
    follower_userID      NUMBER NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT  XPKPledge PRIMARY KEY (pledge_ID),
CONSTRAINT gets FOREIGN KEY (artist_userID) REFERENCES ArtistMember (user_ID),
CONSTRAINT makes FOREIGN KEY (follower_userID) REFERENCES FollowerMember (user_ID)
);
```

When I try to insert a null value I get the error below.

```
INSERT INTO pledge VALUES(559, 'null','1-FEB-2016', 3850, 85275, 88128);

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error starting at line : 209 in command -
INSERT INTO pledge VALUES(559, 'NULL','1-FEB-2016', 3850, 85275, 88128)
Error at Command Line : 209 Column : 13
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: Look at the errors again. The `insert` is getting ORA-00942. The ORA-00904 is coming from the `create table`. Fix that first. When you do want to insert null, it should be just `null`, not `'null'` - that is a string literal, not null. And don't rely on implicit date conversions, as you are with the start date.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `SQL Error: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier` is probably being caused because your `FOREIGN KEY`s are referencing a column that does not exist - check that the column names are spelt correctly and that should solve it (and then your `CREATE TABLE` statement will work).

```
CREATE TABLE ArtistMember (
  user_ID INT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE FollowerMember (
  user_ID INT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE pledge (
    pledge_ID            INT CONSTRAINT  XPKPledge PRIMARY KEY,
    pledge_endDate       DATE NULL,
    pledge_startDate     DATE NULL,
    pledge_amount        DECIMAL(9,2) NULL  CONSTRAINT  Currency_1322638346 CHECK (pledge_amount >= 0),
    artist_userID        INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT gets REFERENCES ArtistMember (user_ID),
    follower_userID      INT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT makes REFERENCES FollowerMember (user_ID)
);

INSERT INTO ArtistMember VALUES ( 85275 );
INSERT INTO FollowerMember VALUES( 88128 );
INSERT INTO pledge VALUES(
  559,
  NULL,              -- Use NULL and not 'NULL'
  DATE '2016-02-01', -- Use a Date literal and not a string literal
  3850,
  85275,
  88128
);
```

If you just use the string in `'1-FEB-2016'` then Oracle will implicitly try to convert the string literal using the `TO_DATE()` function with the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter as the format mask. If they match then it will work but this is a client variable so can be changed and then the query will break without the code having changed (and be a pain to debug). The simple answer is to ensure that you compare date value by either using `TO_DATE()` and specifying the format mask (as per the query above) or to use an ANSI date literal `DATE '2016-02-01'` (which is independent of the NLS settings).

Answer (score 0):

Insert an empty string `''` to a NUMBER column, Oracle will insert `NULL`.

For example, `col_2` has data type is date field or `number(12,0)` (any datatype what not date field), SQL statement set `NULL` value for `col_2` like this:

```
insert into foo (col_1, col_2) values ('abc', '');
```

or

```
insert into foo (col_1, col_2) values ('abc', NULL);
```

(it is `NULL`, not `'NULL'` or `"NULL"`)